# Android Development Problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wouldn't say I am new to android development (been doing it for 6+ months) or to programming languages in general (been doing ruby on rails and C# for almost 1 year) nor am I an expert (or even "experienced" enough to do it full time as a job) but I seem to be running into issues that I didn't have with C# or Ruby on Rails.

Every five seconds I seem to stumble into a difficult challenge that has been making progress very slow. For example, I have used the official android development website since I started but it seems more of an "overview" than tutorial. With almost every tutorial or guide provided there are steps needed to complete the application that do not feature in the guide themselves. The "ActionBar Tab Menu" tutorial shows how the tabbed menu works and also how to change it from text to icons... but at no point do they give you example code, or decent instructions to actually get a working example. (shown below)

```
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new FirstFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SecondFragment();
        case 2:
            return new ThirdFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It took almost three days to figure out the solution after using google and every resource available on the android dev site (stackoverflow actually provided the answer in the end) to fine a few lines of code.

Twelve tutorials/guides (whatever you want to call them) I've done now from the android dev site and every time I find portions of missing code or explanations/examples that make it a painful process trying to learn more "complicated" actions you can perform.

Is it the way I am trying to learn Java and android? I recently bought a ruby on rails book (pragmatic programmers e-commerce) and when I got the the final section (creating orders for the imaginary admin to see) it basically said... we're going to skip over this section because the code isn't complicated enough to warrant space in the book.

Is this the general idea? Not to be given "copy paste" code but rather that I must figure out a solution (or find an example) by myself, or is there a better way to go about learning android programming (maybe another steady resource I can use instead of/as well as the android dev topics)

Any information or opinions (especially from hobby devs or android devs who develop for a living) would be very welcome.

Comment: Take a class. Read a book. But ot for so.

Comment: "Take a class. Read a book" is what I would read on HowTo's website guide for "Becoming an android developer". I was asking for practical advice that contained more than 10 words to be honest. Your reputation indicates you are respected on the forum, but at the same time (unless I'm so new to developing I can't see you're just messing with me) your answer is disappointingly vague for someone with 80K + reputation.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, and not an answer. And it's the answer-there's no magic solution. The last four words aren't part of the answer, they're telling you that the question is off-topic for stack overflow. So the comment is really only six words, an even better reputation/answer ratio.

Comment: If you did not intend to give me a significant answer, and you were not being pretentious with the "there is no magic answer" line I fail to understand why comment at all. If my question is off-topic surely you can dislike it, report or downvote it.

Comment: I did flag it. The bottom line is that if you want complete Android app info without digging for it, you'll need to take a class or read a book. I don't understand why this is surprising, let alone pretentious. There are very few complete tutorials out there-if there were, you'd likely have found them already. Please don't take my advice if you're unhappy with it-easy enough.

Comment: It was pretentious because "Take a class. Read a book" was a painfully obvious answer to give and posted for the sake of posting it rather than to actually add something constructive. You flagged my post, no need to comment something so vague really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's an answer from someone with 13 years in the industry.  Its the way you're going about it.  If you're looking for copy paste answers, you aren't really learning what you're doing-  on Android, Ruby, or any other platform.  What you're doing is barely even programming-  you're just hacking something together that barely works.

What you should be doing is every time you need to do something, try to figure it out yourself.  When you do end up needing to look up code, don't just copy paste it.  Study it.  Understand every line of it.  Understand WHY they're doing it that way, not just the HOW they're doing it.  You should be doing the regardless of what language/platform you're on.

If you don't do this, you will not progress as a programmer.  You'll stay what you are-  a barely competent programmer who can kind of hack things together if someone else figures out how to do everything first.  But you'll never be able to work on complex tasks, never be able to do anything new, never be able to design complex software, and you'll always be at the low end of both the pay and respect scale of your peers.

Luckily you can climb out of this position-  if you're willing to put in the work.  But it's going to take time and effort.

Comment: Android is difficult without baseline information, and without good materials, it *is* difficult to dive in to. I've been developing professionally for 25+ years, semi-pro since grade school, and I'm reasonably good at it. Any sufficiently complex system can make even the most experienced look like an incompetent amateur until the ecosystem is digested. You can't just "figure out" how everything works together without documentation.

Comment: One thing to make thing seems better than my comments may have appeared-  the fact the OP is on here and open to the idea that he may need to change how he's doing things is a very positive sign.  And if he's at about the 1 year mark of programming, he's right about where I'd expect.  Its just time for him to take the next step if he wants to progress.

Comment: This is the best answer (previous and recently) I've had. I've known about the advantages of "learning" over "hacking together" but the way in which you summarized it made me re-think how I should go about following a tutorial or reading a book. Thats been everybodys advice "just read more books" but thank you for taking the time to explain that just developing using other people's code isn't going to get me the results I want.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree that Android is much more difficult than, say, web based programming of many sorts.  But there's plenty of documentation on the basics out there.  Where I had to call the OP out is that he seems to expect fully coded examples for everything that he can copy and tweak.  While we all do that from time to time, we shouldn't be dependent on it.

Comment: @Aluxzi I wish you luck going forward.  If you want, feel free to reach out through my facebook (its in my profile).  I won't spoon feed you answers, but I may be able to help by providing the right clues or questions.

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't expect fully coded examples but at the same time some of the steps needed are confusing (when I first started understanding the difference between an activity and fragment was difficult) and there is no extra advice given... it doesnt say, right we're not going to give you the code for the actionbar tabs, but each individual tab can be represented by a seperate fragment etc.. it just stops at a certain point, doesn't even mention the parts that might be missing and carries on with the next section.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to agree with @Gabe here.

It's all well and good to be taking code from other places and putting it together, but the fact is that you shouldn't do that as a first recourse.  Sure - if you forget the exact syntax, or can't remember what arguements a method takes or something go for it - but if you're sitting there googling every single thing you try to accomplish you're never going to get any growth.

1)  Start reading API's.  Read the Specs for these apis.  The Android Tutorials are more than sufficient if you take the time to familiarize yourself with the classes and interfaces which are utilized within them.  If all you do when you look at one of these tutorials is copy paste code you're accomplishing nothing.

2)  Start designing your own stuff.  Follow the KISS paradigm - keep it simple stupid.  SO when you do the action bar stuff, start with just the bar.  Does that show up?  Great put one tab it.  Make that work.  Ok make that tab a fragment.  Now activate with the Fragment listeners.  Take the time to understand the lifecycles etc... of the involved elements.

3)  When switching between lagnuages/paradigms realize that you're going to have to acclimate yourself to the new environment.  I code in C(++), Python, JS, and Java most of the time.  Learning, coding and working in each of these is different.  A big part of this is being patient, and most importantly READING THE DOCUMENTATION.  Note: not tutorials.  Not code snippets. The actual language docs.  The ones that explain the philosophy, the trade offs, the goals, the accomplishments, the structure - those docs.

4)  Don't be so hard on yourself.  I've been coding for almost 4 years now - two professionally.  I still consider myself a total newbie.  I'm constantly lost, learning and trying to figure out things I've never seen before.  As I get better less and less of what is my 'knowledge' frontier is even covered in online/other resources.  This is where patience, thorough reading and taking the time to think come in.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Unfortunatly I do have to admit a lot of my recent time has been using/following tutorials. I don't think I have spent as much time reading the language docs as I probably should have so I will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: No problem.  It's not unfortunate - as @Gabe says in his comments above - you're new and you're where I would anticipate giving your experieince.  It's just time to step it up, if that's what you really want.  The good news is it's easy:  Take your time, read things thuroughly, and relax.

Comment: Both yourself and @Gabe have helped me change the way I look at how I am developing. I thought if I did x amount of tutorials eventually, I would have learned enough to start developing "my own" android apps.. but now I think that I will immerse myself in the documentation and actually find how how it all works individually and together (as well as maybe a tutorial here and there) instead of hoping to get a better understanding of it later.

Comment: Something to realize - you weren't wrong.  You simply are reaching the ends of what that method of learning will give you.  You've reached a point where you're READY to learn in this new way.

Answer (score 0):

I like very much the Vogella

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html

He show the solution step by step and give the full code in the end.